# If $ a_0=1 , a_1=1$ and $a_n=a_{n-1}a_{n-2} + 1$ for $n>1$ whether $a_{465}$ and $a_{466}$ are odd or even.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to find whether $a_{465}$ and $a_{466}$ is odd or even.

After solving we know it goes like first 2 number i.e $a_0$ and $a_1$ are odd, then $a_2$ = even then again next two numbers are odd so I tried using concept of sequence and series but obviously it's not working out for me as the series doesn't form an AP. How shall I approach this kind of problems?

Comment: I did ? I am new so it'll take bit time for me to get used to it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Try finding the first lets say $9$ elements of the sequence.Which numbers are even and which are odd?

Comment: So here's what you've asked for 
$a_0=1, a_1=1, a_2=2, a_3=3, a_4=7,a_5=22,a_6=155,a_7=3411,a_8=529946$

If we see the sequence first 2 nos. are odd and one even this goes on and on.

Comment: That's right now you can prove this by induction or try using the fact that if $a_{n-1}a_{n-2}$ is even then $a_n$ is odd

Comment: Okay thanks. I guess I need to work on my common sense more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that if $a_{n-1}$ is odd and $a_{n-2}$ is odd then $a_n=a_{n-1}a_{n-2}+1$ is even

Since the sequence starts from $0$ so we have that $a_2=\text{even}$ now lets assume that $a_{3k+2}$ is even for every $k$ and $a_{3k+1},a_{3k}$ is odd for every $k$ by induction

The base case $a_0,a_1$ is odd and $a_2$ is even.

The induction hypothesis for $n=k$ that $a_{3k},a_{3k+1}$ are odd and $a_{3k+2}$ is even then for $n=k+1$ we have that

- Since $a_{3k+2}$ is even then
  $\color{blue}{a_{3k+3}}=\color{red}{a_{3k+2}}\color{blue}{a_{3k+1}}+\color{blue}1=\color{red}{\text{even}}+\color{blue}{\text{odd}}=\color{blue}{\text{odd}}$
- We also have that
  $\color{blue}{a_{3k+4}}=\color{blue}{a_{3k+3}}\color{red}{a_{3k+2}}+\color{blue}1=\color{red}{\text{even}}+\color{blue}{\text{odd}}=\color{blue}{\text{odd}}$
- Then $\color{red}{a_{3k+5}}=\color{blue}{a_{3k+4}a_{3k+3}+1}=\color{blue}{\text{odd}}+\color{blue}{\text{odd}}=\color{red}{\text{even}}$

Comment: Thanks for proper explanation.

Comment: @ItiShree No problem,if you find an answer useful upvote it and accept the most useful answer by clicking the check mark under the downvote arrow,that way the question moves out of the "unanswered queue" for more info look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I did but it won't count my upvote until I reach 15 reputation points or something.

Comment: @ItiShree Ah yeah you're right I forgot though you probably can accept answers,if you can when you accept an answer you get $+2$ reputation which will help you get privileges quicker.

Comment: Ok cool I'll do it from now.